# Json encode проблема с пробелом

Tags: php, html, json

Почему, если обернуть массив в json_encode:

```
<button id="button"
        data-legend = {{ json_encode(['In time', 'Half time', 'Overtime'])}}
>Button</button>
```

В итоге получается:

```
data-legend="[&quot;In" time&quot;,&quot;half="" time&quot;,&quot;overtime&quot;]=""
```

А хотелось бы получить массив по такому типу:

```
data-production="["odit","porro","necessitatibus","ut","omnis","perspiciatis"]"
```

Comment: шаблонизатор blade? верно?

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer да, верно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была не с пробелом, а в правильности передачи параметров в json_encode, т.е. вместо json_encode(['In time', 'Half time', 'Overtime']), в данном случае необходимо использовать json_encode(array('In time', 'Half time', 'Overtime')).

Answer (score 1):

Дело не в пробелах, у вас в атрибутах не могут быть кавычки, т.е. ваш пример:

```
data-production="["odit","porro","necessitatibus","ut","omnis","perspiciatis"]"
```

это просто невалидный HTML. Вероятно отсюда всё ваши проблемы. Покопайтесь в настройках `json_encode` чтобы он, например, корректно вам кавычки эскейпил в `&quot;` у вашего JSON. Ну или по обстоятельствам, просто не совсем понятно что именно вы хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: мне нужно в итоге в js получить массив этих значений, т.е. ['In time', 'Half time', 'Overtime'], а сейчас получаю так ["In

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о шаблонизаторе blade, то вам нужно использовать нотацию `{!! !!}`

```
<button id="button"
        data-legend = "{!! json_encode(['In time', 'Half time', 'Overtime'])!!}"
>Button</button>
```

Comment: получается такое http://prntscr.com/kkpian , почему он после In добавляет ковычку?